# How do I force Catalyst::Controller::REST to render a view following a POST request, if no content type was specified?

Tags: perl, rest, catalyst

I am hacking together a RESTful server in Catalyst. Although this is nominally a strict RESTful service, I don't really care about the caller's accepted response types, I always want it to be XML rendered by Template Toolkit; so I have my own view class (based on `Catalyst::View::TT`) with a 'process' method that just sets the content-type and calls the superclass:

```
sub process {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    $c->response->content_type('text/xml; charset=utf-8');
    $self->SUPER::process($c);
}
```

This view class also has a line in the config block, `"TEMPLATE_EXTENSION => '.tt2'"`, which I assume is how Catalyst knows that when I say something like `$c->stash->{template} = 'world/view.tt2'` then the `.tt2` extension means that it should use this class (otherwise I'm not sure how Catalyst ever knows what view class to use).

I also have a 'RenderView' ActionClass on the end action, to override the default REST controller behavior (which delegates to whatever serializer matches the caller's accepted response types) and instead fall through to the default view. This just looks like `sub end : ActionClass('RenderView') { }`

When I test this with GET, I see the process method appearing at the end of the action chain, and the view renders correctly:

```
.------------------------------------------------------------+-----------.
| Action                                                     | Time      |
+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| /world/begin                                               | 0.000123s |
| /auto                                                      | 0.000139s |
| /world/world_id                                            | 0.268140s |
| /world/view                                                | 0.259048s |
| /world/view_end                                            | 0.000083s |
| /view_end_GET                                              | 0.110241s |
| /world/end                                                 | 0.049207s |
|  -> Zoo::View::XML->process                                | 0.048564s |
'------------------------------------------------------------+-----------'
```

However, my POST requests don't seem to be rendering the view: by default I get a `Content-type unsupported...` error message instead of the body I want, along with a 415 UNSUPPORTED error code, even though I have set `$c->stash->{template}`. Note the lack of a call to `Zoo::View::XML->process` at the end of the POST request's action chain:

```
.------------------------------------------------------------+-----------.
| Action                                                     | Time      |
+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| /world/begin                                               | 0.030158s |
| /auto                                                      | 0.000116s |
| /world/world_id                                            | 0.001228s |
| /world/lock                                                | 0.000915s |
| /world/lock_end                                            | 0.000049s |
| /lock_end_POST                                             | 0.809860s |
| /world/end                                                 | 0.000279s |
'------------------------------------------------------------+-----------'
```

Digging deeper, it looks like the RenderView action will silently bail if `$c->response->body` is already set, which (by inserting warn messages) I figured out that it seems to be for the POST request (where the body is set to the "Content-type unsupported" error message by the time it reaches my `lock_end` subroutine) but not the GET request (for which `$c->response->body` remains undefined).

Anyone happen to know why POST is being picky about the response type, while GET is not? How can I tell POST to stop worrying about the requested content-type (or lack of it)? By looking at [the Catalyst::Controller::REST documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aController%3a%3aREST) it seems like maybe I need to specify a default deserializer which just does nothing? But how exactly?

Thanking you for your help....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `__PACKAGE__->config(default => 'text/xml');` to my controller class seemed to do the trick.

Comment: The documentation in `http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Catalyst-Action-RenderView-0.16/lib/Catalyst/Action/RenderView.pm` says it should be `__PACKAGE__->config(default_view => 'text/xml');`.

Comment: @ViniciusJoséLatorre that's for the C:A:RenderView, this question is on C:A:REST